# Stripe create-checkout-session not loading

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, stripe-payments

I'm following the steps for Stripe's payment setup in Node, but I can't quite get my page to redirect to the pre-built Stripe checkout form. The post request to "/create-checkout-session" just says "pending" in the network tab.

Can someone explain where exactly that route should direct to? The tutorial makes it seem like it should be {localhost address}/create-checkout-session, but I can't see how that all connects back to Stripe's servers.

My Server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
var dotenv = require("dotenv");
const Stripe = require("stripe");
const stripe = Stripe(
  "***************************** (secret key would go here) ************************"
);
app.get(
  "/checkout-session",
  async (req, res) => {
    const { sessionId } = req.query;
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sessionId);
    res.send(session);
  });
  app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
    const { priceId } = req.body;

    try {
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        mode: "subscription",
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        line_items: [
          {
            price: priceId,
            quantity: 1
          }
        ],
        success_url: "localhost:3000/listings?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
        cancel_url: "localhost:3000/stripe"
      });
      res.send({
        sessionId: session.id
      });
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400);
      return res.send({
        error: {
          message: e.message
        }
      });
    }
  })


app.listen(4242, () =>
  console.log(`Node server listening at http://localhost:${4242}/`)
```

Client Side

```
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <head>
      <title>Checkout</title>
      <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button @click.prevent="createSession" ref="checkout">Subscribe</button>
    </body>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
var createCheckoutSession = function(priceId) {
  console.log("create checkout");
  return fetch("http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      priceId: "price_1I641zIXVRhKifjKEM8o7Fat"
    })
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log("posted");
    return result.json();
  });
};

export default {
  methods: {
    createSession() {
      console.log("called function");
      createCheckoutSession().then(function(data) {
        console.log("redirected");
        // Call Stripe.js method to redirect to the new Checkout page
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: data.sessionId
        });
        console.log("redirected").then(handleResult);
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why is `app.post` nested within `app.get`?

Comment: oh oops, just fixed that, same issue persists unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry to be nitpicky (just want to the reason you're seeing "pending" before getting to the Stripe issues) - You're also missing semicolons after the app.post()

Comment: did you got a solution , please post for us

Answer (score 0):

So, not sure if this is what you need, but I'm having a similar issue. I have the "Cannot POST /create-checkout-session" error. To fix this, I added a proxy in my package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4242",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

However, I don't think this should be used in production, as I get "Invalid Host Header" error on GCP, and one should not "dangerously disable host check" for prod. I'm trying to figure out how to run without proxy, but haven't figured out yet. I will post an update if I find a solution.

**EDIT**

I found my solution without proxy. It was just to add the full url like so:

```
  const ProductDisplay = () => (
    <section>
      <form
        action="https://backend-dot-fliermapper.appspot.com/create-checkout-session"
        method="POST"
      >
        <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
        <input type="hidden" value={fileList.length} name="noOfFiles" />
        <input type="hidden" value={mapName} name="apName" />
      </form>
    </section>
  );
```